# Postgresql trigger row not affected

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have try to make a trigger on a table call product. After inserting a product i get an error, that "NEW" variable  is not affected yet.

Here is the trigger and user-defind function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateProduitQteInitiale() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $example_table$
    BEGIN
       IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN      
       UPDATE produit set qtestock= NEW.qteinitial where produit.pid = NEW.pid ; 
       return NEW ;
      END IF;
      RETURN NULL;
    END;
$example_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And here is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER qteInitialTrigger AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE  ON produit
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE updateProduitQteInitiale();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is pid your primary id? Not sure what you want to do but I assume you want to set to the column qtestock value from column qteinitial (on the same row!). If I guessed it right then you can do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateProduitQteInitiale() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $example_table$
BEGIN
  NEW.qtestock = NEW.qteinitial;     
  return NEW;
END;
$example_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER qteInitialTrigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE  ON produit
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE updateProduitQteInitiale();
```